# Could not release memory when using MediaLibDemo3x library with ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

Sorry for my english first. I'm building application that play RMTP video from my server. So I using [MediaLibDemo3x](https://github.com/slavavdovichenko/MediaLibDemos3x) with RTMPStreamPlayer to play video on client side. Thanks to [slavavdovichenko](https://github.com/slavavdovichenko) for this. But the problem is when I stop playing video and clean stream, my simulators(devices) memory can not be released. So every time I setup new stream, memory using is duplicate. What can I do to release memory used when stop playing and clean stream? Here is code:

Setup

```
[decoder setupStream:url];
```

Stop and clean

```
[decoder cleanupStream];
decoder.streamImageView = nil;
decoder = nil;
```

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any other reference to the component?
Have you tried with a simple project where you simply create / destroy it multiple times to be sure the problem is not on MediaLibDemo site?

Comment: Thanks for your question. I have used example demo project from github and problem still happen. So I think that is not occur from my project.

Comment: Good, I think it should be related to the Component itself.

Comment: :) I think so. Thanks for answers.